# How to add music on iPod Touch 4th/5th gen from iTunes on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, ipod-touch

I am trying to download some music from my computer onto my iPod touch 4th generation. I have searched the Internet but have had no luck finding out how. How do you transfer music from iTunes on a PC onto an iPod Touch 4th generation?

Comment: [How to Set Up & Sync iPod Touch](http://ipod.about.com/od/tes1/ss/ipod-touch-setu.htm). Instructions are for 2/3/4/5 gen.

Answer (score 1):

Here are instructions

1. Plug your iPod into your computer. ITunes should open up.
2. Go to the music tab.
3. Add the music that you want from it.
4. Sync and when compete you may remove the charger from it